# How can I make vim highlight the current line on only the active buffer?

Tags: vim

I have set cursorline in my vimrc.  Is there any way to make vim highlight only the current line in the active buffer instead of all buffers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try:

```
au BufEnter * setlocal cursorline
au BufLeave * setlocal nocursorline
```

Comment: Unfortuately, it only works most of the time. See my answer for a better alternative.

Answer (score 28):

The problem with the `BufEnter` / `BufLeave` hooks used in Zsolt's answer is that they don't fire when moving to an adjacent window that displays the same buffer. I have used the following successfully:

```
augroup CursorLine
    au!
    au VimEnter,WinEnter,BufWinEnter * setlocal cursorline
    au WinLeave * setlocal nocursorline
augroup END
```

Answer (score 3):

To Zsolt's answer I would add:

```
au WinLeave * setLocal nocursorline
```

This improves the behavior when moving between two windows on the same buffer.

Answer (score 3):

The weakness of all the short `:autocmd` solutions here is that you cannot make exceptions like disabling the cursorline for a particular window or making it permanent for (another) window. Any change of `'cursorline'` will be overwritten by the next move to another window.

My [CursorLineCurrentWindow plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4178) handles these exceptions through a more elaborate logic.